# Where is the geometry node's scale node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: Looking for the scale node that connects a vector output to offset input portrayed in the image below.]

Looking to add a scale node that connects a vector output to an offset input portrayed in the image above.

Comment: it's the vector math node

Comment: Thank you, that is correct!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just to be able to close this question, a short answer:*

Most mathematical operations *hide* behind the nodes `Math` and `Vector Math`, which can be found in the category **Utilities** and **Vector** respectively.

So if you see a node that does not appear with its name in the list of available nodes, it is almost certainly one of these two nodes whose property has been set to a specific mathematical operation, and thus also shows the corresponding name in the title.

The operations available in [Vector Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/vector/vector_math.html) are:

[image]

The operations available in [Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html) are:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer! You went above and beyond.

Comment: @JustinColeman You are welcome!